# Error: Return value must be of type View|Closure|string, none returned

Tags: laravel

the Error ***App\View\Components\vodplay::render(): Return value must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|Closure|string, none returned*** is showing is component class, code was working and I didn't change this class, I don't know whats wrong, please help

**Error in flareapp:** https://flareapp.io/share/lm2KRJEP

this component class:

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\View\Component;
use App\Models\Video;
use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\User;
use Shetabit\Multipay\Invoice;
use Shetabit\Payment\Facade\Payment;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class vodplay extends Component
{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     */
    public $iding;
    public function __construct($iding)
    {
        //
        $this->id = $iding;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     */
    public function render(): View|Closure|string
    {
        
        $price = Video::where('id',$this->id)->first();
        $price = $price->price;
        // dd($price);
        $videodata = Video::where('id',$this->id)->first();
        $phonenumber = Session('phonenumber');
        
        $ispaidcount = Order::where('userphone',$phonenumber)->where('contentid', $this->id)->count();
        
// بررسی اینکه آیا پرداختی داشته یا محصول رایگان بوده ؟
        if ($price == '0' || $price == NULL) {
            return view('components.vodplay')->with('videodata',$videodata);
        } elseif ($ispaidcount > 0) {
            $timelimit = Order::where('userphone',$phonenumber)->where('contentid', $this->id)->orderBy('starttime','asc')->first();
            $starttime = $timelimit->starttime;
            $limit = $timelimit->seconds;
            $carbon = new Carbon($starttime);
            $now = Carbon::now();
            $endtime = $carbon->addSeconds($limit);
            // dd($starttime,$limit,$endtime);
// بررسی اینکه آیا پرداختی اعتبار دارد
            if ($now->greaterThan($endtime)) {
                $preurl = URL::previous();
                Session(['preurl'=>$preurl]);
                Session(['contentid'=>$this->id]);
                // Do all things together in a single line.
                return Payment::purchase(
                (new Invoice)->amount($price), 
                function($driver, $transactionId) {
                // Store transactionId in database.
                // We need the transactionId to verify payment in the future.
                }
                )->pay()->render();
            } else {
                return view('components.vodplay')->with('videodata',$videodata);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code should create an invoice for user or allow user to watch video if payment was accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically none of your if conditions are hit, when you typehint it to return something and nothing is returned, that is the error you get.

Return a default view and you will be fine, but probably the reason why your if statements are not hit is just as important.

```
if ($price == '0' || $price == NULL) {
    // something
} elseif ($ispaidcount > 0) {
    // something else
}

return view('components.default'); // or whatever view could be the default.
```